# Decode and Union in Hibernate

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm developing a new service. I have been provided with a SQL to work around. But this have proven to be a rather difficult issue.

I have tried to use the "@formula" and adding the Decode function to my hibernate.cfg.xml. And I haven't seen any work around that issue. I tried to run the code without the Decode and Union issue arise.

Controller

```
    public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> listAll() {
        logger.info("ListAllApplications");
        List<Object> allApp = null;

        try {
            allApp = Service.listAll();
            logger.info("return ListAll");

            if (allApp == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(400).body(null);
            }

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(allApp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(500).body(allApp);
        }
    }
```

Logic

```
    public List<Object> listAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        logger.info("Request AllApplications :session");
        String hql = ""
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        logger.info("Request Join: :query");
        List<Object> results = query.list();
        return results;
    }
```

Query in the String HQL above

```
    'String 3', 'String 4', t.initial_state) m), t.bmp from com.model.Table1 T 
    where t.initial_state = 'F' and exists (select 'X' from com.model.Table2 b where t.table_info = b.table_info 
    and t.table_app = b.table_app and t.version = b.version and b.block != 'S')"; 
    UNION 
    select a.table_info, a.table_app, a.version, desc, initial_state, bmp from com.model.Table1 a, 
    com.model.Table3 b, com.model.Table2 c where a.table_info  
    IN ('LDAP') and a.table_info = b.table_info and a.table_app = b.table_app 
    and a.version = b.version and a.table_info = c.table_info and a.table_app = c.table_app 
    and a.version = c.version and c.block != 'S' order by 1,4
```

I would like to be able to have the select as it was given. But any solution similar would do fine.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't work around the mentionet issues. So I tried with a DB View, making the query in the View. Completely solved the problem. Just created a pseudomodel in my code and changed to a simple Query.